# .NET Core 7 gives "Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'IServiceProvider'." the second time I call an handler

Tags: .net-7.0, mediatr

This example is a simplification of the code I have:

```
    private readonly ISender _sender;
    private readonly ILogger<UserAccountsService> _logger;
    public UserAccountsService(ISender sender, ILogger<UserAccountsService> logger)
    {
        _sender = sender;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async void RefreshAccountsFromApi(Guid userId, Z_IF_WEB_LOGINResponse pluralUserAccounts)
    {
        // Get user accounts for this user
        var getUserByIdQuery = new GetUserByIdQuery(userId);
        Result<User> resultUser = await _sender.Send(getUserByIdQuery);
        resultUser = await _sender.Send(getUserByIdQuery); //gets an error
    }
```

Everytime I call a handler a second time I get an error:

> Cannot access a disposed object.
> Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.

This is my DI registration of both Mediatr and my service:

```
services.AddMediatR(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(assembly);
        cfg.AddOpenBehavior(typeof(LoggingPipelineBehavior<,>));
    });

    services.AddTransient<IUserAccountsService, UserAccountsService>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. After noticing that I had an async method returning void instead of Task and not waiting in the call of the method.

```
private readonly ISender _sender;
private readonly ILogger<UserAccountsService> _logger;
public UserAccountsService(ISender sender, ILogger<UserAccountsService> logger)
{
    _sender = sender;
    _logger = logger;
}

public async Task RefreshAccountsFromApi(Guid userId, Z_IF_WEB_LOGINResponse pluralUserAccounts)
{
    // Get user accounts for this user
    var getUserByIdQuery = new GetUserByIdQuery(userId);
    Result<User> resultUser = await _sender.Send(getUserByIdQuery);
    resultUser = await _sender.Send(getUserByIdQuery); //gets an error
}
```

I still don't understand why Mediatr did not like how it was and why for the first call was OK.